# How does Facebook like Messenger subscription ‘opt in’ to work?

Tags: facebook, chatbot

My chatbot was not approved by Facebook because it uses pages_messaging_subscriptions but doesn’t ask the user to opt in to receiving a daily message.

In Facebook’s guidelines it says “Subscription messaging must be opted into by a recipient”.

I’m going to add an opt in but what do you think qualifies as ‘opting in’ in Facebook’s eyes? I can’t find any documentation on it.

If I simply show a message saying ‘**Reply yes to opt in to receive daily messages**’ or ‘**By starting a conversation you agree to receive daily messages**’, do you think that will be enough? Or is there some other way that Facebook expects opt ins to be dealt with?

Comment: just by starting a conversation? does not sound like it´s enough. after all, you just start a conversation by sending a message to a page, you may not even know about any message bot. opt in means: don´t do it, unless the user specifically approved it. but that´s actually an opinionated question and not really on topic on stackoverflow, i´m afraid.

Comment: I agree that the user needs to specifically approve it but my question here is - how does Facebook like the user to approve it? What counts as 'approval'? Is there some particular action the user needs to take?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview#messaging_types lists the three ways the user can opt-in.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. You're absolutely right. I had already read that list but was confused because "Person sends a message to a business" is what my users are already doing. I'm just going to try adding some more description and submitting for review again.